# High I/O because of MariaDB

Tags: debian

i'm using nginx with php-fpm and mariadb. Sometimes my pages are loading slow. By checking munin I saw that my average I/O waiting time is very high, up to 8 seconds. In the php-slowlog are mysql-functions listed as reason, for example mysql_query(). I try to tweak the mariadb server (e.g. increase cache, move tmp dir from hdd to a ramdisk). But my I/O gets randomly high.

[image]

For example at the beginning of the graph. I thought I fixed the problem, but then the waiting time increases without any visible reason. When I restart mariadb it goes rapidly down (you can see how it goes down at the end, I restarted mariadb here).

I'm not really using much I/O, the peak is about 8MB/s:

[image]

Noticeable is that the ratio of Table_locks_immediate to Table_locks_waited is increasing. As i restart mariadb, it was 2.5%. The server is up for ~ 30 minutes now and it had increased to 3.5%. I also noticed that when the server is hanging the number of running threads (Threads_running) is high (up to 30). When this number goes down, the server stops hanging.

My my.cnf:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
sync_binlog = 3

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
#tmpdir     = /tmp
tmpdir      = /var/mysqltmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
log-bin=/var/mysqltmp/mysql-bin.log
#log=/var/mysqltmp/mysql.log
log-error=/var/mysqltmp/mysql-error.log
log-slow-queries=/var/mysqltmp/mysql-slowquery.log

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

max_tmp_tables      = 100
max_connections     = 150
connect_timeout     = 5
#wait_timeout            = 600
wait_timeout        = 800
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
#sort_buffer_size        = 4M
sort_buffer_size    = 8M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
max_heap_table_size     = 128M
tmp_table_size      = 128M
#tmp_table_size          = 64M

# * MyISAM
myisam_recover          = BACKUP
key_buffer_size         = 256M
#open-files-limit   = 2000
table_open_cache    = 1000
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

#concurrent_insert  = 2
#read_buffer_size        = 2M
read_buffer_size    = 4M
#read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 2M

# * Query Cache Configuration
query_cache_limit       = 256M
query_cache_size        = 256M
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
query_cache_type        = ON
#table_cache                    = 400
table_open_cache        = 2000
join_buffer_size        = 4M

# * Logging and Replication
log_warnings        = 2
slow_query_log      = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 128M

# * InnoDB
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size    = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 32M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
#innodb_flush_method    = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_method     = O_DSYNC

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
#key_buffer     = 16M
key_buffer             = 32M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: How much RAM do you have and how big is the database?

Comment: I've 16GB RAM. The main database is about 570MB big and the second one 300MB. The main database is from a CMS hosted on the server. The second database is a non public testing area so only two people can access it.

Answer (score 2):

If most of your tables are **InnoDB**, increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to at least the sum of your databases or put `2GB` instead. If this server is only run database service, put these values to ~60% or 70% of total memory, your database will fit entirely in memory.

If most of your tables are **MyISAM**, increase the `key_buffer_size` in the same way.

For MyISAM, set `concurrent_insert` to `2`.

`query_cache_size` above `64MB` is waste of memory.

Run `mysqlcheck -o -A` periodically to improve indexes statistics for internal mysql query planner.

Avoid queries who do `full_scan`.

Lower `innodb_io_capacity` to `100` or `120` if you have a single disk storage or simple RAID.

Use `XFS` to give the advantage of **concurrent write in same file**.

Mount your fs with `noatime` option.

Avoid swapping.

Disable unnecessary logs.

Comment: +1. Smells right. Databases ARE IO heavy, and caching as much as possible is the only way. Given this size and server all should fill into ram.